# Is it safe to use find params[:id] in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Expressions like the following are common in Rails:

```
@project = Project.find params[:id] # example 1

@project = current_user.projects.find params[:project_id] # example 2
```

However I realize that `find` also accepts arrays! That would mean unexpected and potentially dangerous behavior of code, which is written with the assumption that `@project` is a single project, not an array.

Now the question is:

- **should I typecast `params[:id].to_s` every time I use it in `find`?**
- should I use strong parameters with `find` in order to avoid arrays? `find params.permit(:id)[:id]`)? (better than `to_s` if you don't want to convert `nil` to `""`)
- are there any other alternatives or **common practices?**

---

The above vulnerability seems to be present **only if the routes doesn't define a param with that name**.

For example:

```
# SAFE routes.rb
resources :projects

# projects_controller.rb
Project.find params[:id]
```

The query `/projects/3?id[]=4&id[]=5` produces only `{id: 3}` as a param. This would make using `Project.find params[:id]` safe: however I cannot find any documentation for this behavior and **I don't know if it's safe to rely on it: maybe it's just by chance**.

Furthermore the following is not equivalent at all and would create a vulnerability in the controllers:

```
# Likely UNSAFE routes.rb
# E.g.: 
# /projects?id=3 => params = {id: 3}
# /projects?id[]=3&id[]=4 => params = {id: [3, 4]}
put '/projects' => 'projects#update'
```

Comment: personally, I use `find_by(id: params[:id])` more often. `find` would break the code if it can't find with given value and results `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error. whereas `find_by` will return `nil` if it can't find anything, and I believe that it's safer in some senses

Comment: The nature of the vulnerability you describe appears to be "an attacker can generate a 500 server error".  Is there a particular sort of escalation you are worried about?

Comment: @JimVanFleet For example Token.find(params[:token]) allows an attacker to try thousands of tokens with just one call

Comment: @lusketeer It's idiomatic Rails to use `find` and let the exception generate a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  How are your params coming in?  Is your `params[:id]` and `params[:project_id]` arriving as route params?  If so then you're safe.

Otherwise you want to use strong params - which should cover you.

Finally, you probably want to use #2 because you don't want users gaining access to projects they don't belong to.